# Con qué formato poner el VALUE de un INPUT del tipo Fecha

Tags: html, date

Tengo un **input** del **type="datetime-local"**, y quiero ponerle una Fecha y Hora por defecto.

Estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="'.$proceso['Fecha'].'">
```

Pero en vez de colocar la fecha, el input se queda en blanco: `(mm/dd/yyyy --:--)`

Cuando lo cambio a `type="text"` me muestra lo siguiente: `2019-05-24 08:40:05`

```html
<input type="datetime-local" value="2019-05-24 08:40:05">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que le estás pasando el `value` del `<input>` en un formato que el tipo `datetime-local` no entiende.

```html
<input type="datetime-local" name="bdaytime" value="2019-05-27T09:22">
```

Cuando el `<input type="datetime-local">` se muestra en blanco al darle un `value` normalmente significa incompatibilidad de formato.

Referencia: [datime-local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#Value)